# Are questions marginally related to games off-topic in any case?

Tags: discussion

I posted a [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1777391/found-and-fix-a-ctd-in-windows-11) about how to investigate a crash in a Windows application.

It was rejected since the application was a game.
I kindly ask you some clarifications:

1. gaming questions are off-topic, but there are 740 questions with the `gaming` tag, where its description is *"For questions related to specialized software and hardware configurations designed for playing games."*. Why only mine is off-topic?
2. the fact that the application I'm talking about was a game is not relevant for the question itself. I asked how to investigate about a crash, which tools I can use to understand why an(y) application crashes. I showed my effort, my researches, my trials. It was a technical question, not how to complete a game level.

Would you clarify me why such a question is not accepted here, please?
And, last but not least, I carefully read the [FAQ](https://superuser.com/tour), but I didn't find that I cannot merely talk about an application that *is* a game. I just cannot ask about a "videogame", but again my question was not about it.

Comment: Ehhh. Can't always trust comments. Game play is off topic but trouble shooting crashes is not and I would consider a close for 'being about games ' invalid

Comment: Please undelete the question so I and others with < 10k reputation can read and review it :)

Comment: @Robotnik question undeleted. As you can see, it was another use with a very high reputation that told me I was off-topic and "rules are rules".

Comment: Of course I'm open to improve my question as needed

Answer (score 8):

I'd say it *was* a valid question - that it was a game didn't really have any bearing on topicality. Questions on *playing* games belong on [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/). Troubleshooting crashing software is on topic for us.

2 close votes do not mean something *is* off topic - it means 2 users felt so and without further closevotes it's stay open. If this question was asked post closure I'd hammer it open. I still might if it does get closed.

Since the deletion was on your end - I'll leave it to you to un delete but to me its a question that is on topic.

Comment: Thanks. Question undeleted. Please review and of course tell me if and how I can improve my question.

Comment: I don't think there's anything particularly wrong with it. More input on troubleshooting options might be fortcoming from users - but I don't see anything you have missed that's obvious

Comment: Just to be clear: I deleted my question not because the two close votes, but for the comments of a high-reputation user that told me I was off-topic several times.

Comment: I'm a higher rep user, if that matters and I don't think they are correct :D